# getting error while calculating estimated gas of contract deployment

Tags: javascript, web3js

```
 const web3 = new Web3(provider)
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(data.contractABI);
        const deployData = contract.deploy({ data: data.contractBytecode, arguments: ["bro"] })
        web3.eth.estimateGas({ from: address[0], data: deployData.encodeABI() })
            .then((gasEstimate) => {
                console.log('Gas Estimate:', gasEstimate);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error estimating gas:', error);
            });
```

-->>> i have already checked the values of provider , contract Abi and contract byte code their values are absolutely fine
i am getting these two error --->

1. Metamask - RPC Error :reverted {code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted'}

2.Error estimating gas
{code: -32000,message: "execution reverted"}

i want to deploy a contract just using web3 library without using truffle or hardhat

Comment: What error do you get?